# “Sorry for bumping into you” in French

Tags: politesse, formulation-idiomatique

How would you say "Sorry for bumping into you" in French?

Comment: http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/bump%20into.  *Excusez-voir de vous avoir bousculé*.

Comment: @Laure You must have made a typo : *Excusez-**moi** de vous avoir bousculé*

Comment: Ahah elle a écrit comme elle parle. 'Scusez voir d'vous avoir bousculé.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  Oui et on ne peut pas éditer les commentaires mais bof... j'avais demandé la fermeture de la question. Aucun effort de recherche...( et en plus l'anglais est ambigu, perso je ne dirais pas ça si je bouscule quelqu'un).

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> *Excusez-moi de vous avoir bousculé*

or:

> *Désolée de vous avoir bousculé*

or:

> *Pardon de vous avoir bousculé*

Comment: This is correct - un peu formel, et si on bouscule quelqu'un par exemple, dans une gare bondee, on n'a peut-etre pas le temps d'en dire autant, mais c'est correct.